# Hosting a flash app in a WindowsFormsHost in a Surface application and .CallFunction

Tags: wpf, flash, exception

I'm working on adding a Flash app to a Surface application. It looks to be working just fine (overlaying the Flash app with an almost transparent Surface window to catch the Contacts).

However, if I want to call a Flash function in my SWF (using .CallFunction), I get a E_FAIL exception. It is suggested that a callback function in the SWF might be missing for the defined function, but, although I can't check since the SWF isn't mine, I think that's not the case.

Does anybody have a suggestion why these E_FAIL exceptions might happen?

Thanks,

Bart

Bart Roozendaal, Sevensteps

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Using the proxy as provided in the examples below, did the trick for me. I will go on examining that code later on. For now, it will do!

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_